# Metrics Calculation for Multilabel Classification Problem

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I need to learn how this function works for multilabel problems.

I try to calculate accuracy for to reach same result but i couldnt.
How does it  work?

4 labels in this dataset, y_array is real, y_pred is predicted array.
y is like this;
[0,1,1,1], [1,0,0,0] ...

```
tp = 0
tn = 0
fn = 0
fp = 0
for i in range(len(y_array)):
    for j in range(4) :
        #True
        if ( y_array[i][j] == 1 ) and (y_pred[i][j]  == 1  ) :
            tp = tp + 1
        elif ( y_array[i][j] == 0 ) and (y_pred[i][j]  == 0  ) :
            tn = tn + 1
        #False
        elif ( y_array[i][j] == 0 ) and (y_pred[i][j]  == 1  ) :
            fn = fn + 1
        elif ( y_array[i][j] == 1 ) and (y_pred[i][j]  == 0  ) :
            fp = fp + 1
ac = (tp+tn)/(tp+tn+fp+fn)
print("Accuracy", ac) 
print('Accuracy: {0}'.format(accuracy_score(y_array, y_pred)))
```

They are different from each other, How can i calculate accuracy or other metrics for this multilabel problem?
Is it wrong to use sklearn accuracy metric?

> Accuracy 0.9068711367973193

> Accuracy: 0.7134998676125521

Comment: I didn't understand `y = [0,1,1,1]`. Can y take multiple values?

Comment: y is an array which all elements has 4 values. This problem is a multilabel classification problem.

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy Imagine a face recognition algorithm that wants to see whether Lucas, Macy, John and Christina appear in a video. The algorithm will return an array y=[0, 1, 1, 1] in the case where Macy, John and Christina -if we respect the previous order for which I mentioned the people- actually appear in the video, but Lucas doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [scikit-learn documentation for accuracy_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html):

> for multilabel classification, this function computes subset accuracy:
> the set of labels predicted for a sample must **exactly** match the
> corresponding **set of labels** in y_true.

This means that each label will look something like `[0,0,1,0]` and will need identical match for a **single** Positive (so y_pred will need to be `[0,0,1,0]` as well), and anything that isn't `[0,0,1,0]` will result in a **single** Negative.

In your manual function, you count each partial match separately:
if y_true is `[0,0,1,0]` and y_pred is `[0,1,0,0]`, you count this as 2 True Negatives (in position 0 and 3), 1 False Positive (position 1) and 1 False Negative (position 2). With the formula you use for accuracy, this results in `ac = (0+2)/(0+2+1+1)`, which gives 50% accuracy, while `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score` will be 0%.

If you want to replicate scikit-learn accuracy_score manually, you would need to first check each member of y_array[i], and only then label it as one of the TP,TN,FP,FN.

However seeing as you're dealign with multilabel classification, as per link above, you might want to check out [sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html#sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score), [sklearn.metrics.hamming_loss](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.hamming_loss.html#sklearn.metrics.hamming_loss) or [sklearn.metrics.zero_one_loss](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.zero_one_loss.html#sklearn.metrics.zero_one_loss)

Comment: Thank you, that was very explanatory.  Became so clear to me for the accuracy.  So how are other metrics calculated in multilabel problems?  For example, how is the calculation made in recall for f1 score?  Can I use the tp tn fp fn values ​​in this code?

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman I encourage you to check out https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#precision-recall-f-measure-metrics (especially '3.3.2.9.2. Multiclass and multilabel classification'). It seems these metrics are calculated separately for each label, which can then be averaged overall using different methods (all explained in greater detail in the link I provided). One correction I should note, your approach might be useful when labels are not mutually-exclusive (i.e. when when a single data point can have more than one label)

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman worthy to note, if you use classification_report, this will break down precision, recall, f1 score by class and include averaged values as well.

Comment: Thank you this was so helpfull, i tried to calculate each label f1_score and get average of them the result doesnt be the same. This for all                                                                                  sklearn.metrics.f1_score(y_true=y_array, y_pred=y_pred, average='samples')
loop for this ->   sklearn.metrics.f1_score(y_true=y_array[:,i], y_pred=y_pred[:,i]) then /4,, not same :(

Comment: I really dont get it, it says calculating separately when you add "samples", but when i try to find by calculating separately i cant reach the same result.

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman I must admit I might be out of my depth, but it seems what you're trying to do is `average='macro'` (i.e. calculate metrics for each label, then average it out). 'samples' calculates metrics for each instance, then averages it out. You can check out this DataScience Stack answer on differences between micro and macro averaging: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin

Comment: Yes, I really asked a lot of questions. Thank you very much for your help. I was able to achieve the same results. I think I understand more clearly now. Thank you so much.